# Cant connect to mongoshell MongoDB Enterprise atlas-corj2q-shard-0:PRIMARY>

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I can not connect to mongodb via the shell as I dont know what to enter when the following prompt appears

```
MongoDB Enterprise atlas-corj2q-shard-0:PRIMARY>
```

[image]

Please help

Comment: You are connected to a MongoDB replica set via `mongo` shell. The prompt says so. The `PRIMARY` means the primary member of the replica-set. You can enter a commands like: rs.isMaster() or rs.status() or db or show dbs or show collections, etc.

Comment: @prasad_ can you please add this comment as an answer so that I can accept and close this question?

Answer (score 1):

u are connected to a MongoDB replica set via mongo shell. The prompt says so. The PRIMARY means the primary member of the replica-set. You can enter a commands like: rs.isMaster() or rs.status() or db or show dbs or show collections, etc
via  prasad_